# Testing web apps with Mocha and Chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, bdd, chai

I understand how to test functions that output values with mocha and chai on the browser, but I don't understand how I can use this system to test full fledged web apps. To break it down to something more simple, how can I test that when clicking on a button, a `<div>` that already exists in the HTML is revealed?

I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.codeship.com/mocha-js-chai-sinon-frontend-javascript-code-testing-tutorial/) but this just doesn't apply to applications that already exist. It wants me to create a new `test.html` but that makes no sense if my app relies on pre-existing HTML. It also expects that you should be able to create a `new Foo` and then run tests like does `Foo` have a default `name` parameter. But my application already creates a `Foo` on `document ready`.

Maybe I am missing the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When testing applications, you should not be testing the application as a whole but rather the individual components that your application is comprised of. You test these components individually and in isolation.

Thus you would generally have 'test.html' (to take your example) that incorporates only the elements necessary for you to test your component. Given your first description 'test.html' may consist of only a button and a hidden div. Your test would emulate a button click and then verify that the div is no longer hidden.

This allows you to ensure the behaviour of your code is correct before you integrate it into a larger web application, where it would become much more complicated.

Whilst your application may already create a Foo when the document is ready, that particular code would not (or, should not) be included in your unit-test for Foo itself.

It sounds like you are not using an application framework, which I would recommend. These provide well researched structure for web-applications and usually have a wealth of documentation on testing applications built with them. I would recommend AngularJS (https://angularjs.org/) or React (https://facebook.github.io/react/) but there are many alternatives.

Comment: This app has been in dev and maintenance for 10+ years, there's no chance to switch to React or Angular unfortunately. Getting Bootstrap in there was a miracle itself. Your answer makes sense to me - I didn't think it would be possible to use a test framework to actually test an entire page.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Working with a legacy code-base then, I would separate out sections of code to test a little at a time. But it will be painful unfortunately, however baby steps forward and progress will occur. The documentation for other frameworks is also useful to see how modern frameworks structured themselves to aid in testing.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with testing a web application or any application as a whole. It's generally called "acceptance testing" and unlike unit tests, you do want to be testing the application end-to-end, with all the moving parts working together to make sure the application works in the real world. I.e. if your app is perfect but your hosting company is unreliable, that might come up in acceptance testing, and would need to be fixed.

Comment: Hey Todd, you are correct that you can test applications as a whole, however testing at that level without a base of unit tests for the components is much more error prone. I think I should have re-phrased my reply to make that more obvious and will try to take that into consideration in future replies. The original question seemed to be suggesting a top-down approach, where I meant to suggest building the tests from the bottom-up.